# Pass a variable using Script task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a C# script in the ssis package as mentioned below

```
SqlConnection importTab = new SqlConnection(@"Server=ServerName;  
Integrated Security=true;user=;pwd=;database=DBname");
```

I need to pass the database name (DBName) inside a variable...

May be like this

```
SqlConnection importTab = new SqlConnection(@"Server=ServerName;  
Integrated Security=true;user=;pwd=;database="+"User::Variable" +");"
```

But I know I am wrong...

Comment: You shouldn't have both `Integrated Security=true` AND a user ID and password in the connection string, choose one or the other.

Comment: Use the [Connection String Builder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To use a variable in a script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
code needs to write to the variable.

```
//Example of reading from a variable:
DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;

//Example of writing to a variable:
Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";

//Example of reading from a package parameter:
int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;

//Example of reading from a project parameter:
int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;

//Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

When opening the script task properties you have two fields, `ReadOnlyVariables` and `ReadWriteVariables`. Write your variable name into the according field based on your needs, in your case `User::Variable`.

In the code you can use it like this

```
Dts.Variables["User::Variable"].Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code in the Script task may help you

```
var dbServerName = Dts.Variables["yourVariableName"].Value.ToString();

var sqlConnString = string.Format("Server=ServerName;Integrated Security=true;user=;pwd=;database={0}", dbServerName);

SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);
```